# How to insert multiple values in one column of type number in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have table like

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE  
( 
  temp_acct number(10) NOT NULL, 
  temp_code varchar2(250),
  temp_bal number(10,2),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY(temp_acct)   
);
```

Is it possible to insert multiple values into column temp_bal in one row something like below,I know the syntax is incorrect but is there any way?

```
INTO TEMP_TABLE (temp_acct, temp_code, temp_bal) 
VALUES (1000, 'code100, code101, code102, code103', '1000.00,2000.00,3000.00');
```

Comment: Not like that, no. You could make the column `varchar2`, or - better - of type **nested table**. Either way though, that is a terrible practice - it violates First Normal Form. All your queries will become exceptionally complicated, you will not be able to have proper constraints and indexes, everything will be very inefficient (meaning very slow), etc. That's the wrong data model. You need TWO tables if you can have multiple codes for each account.

Comment: mathguy is right. Don't do that. Read up on normalization, then create a proper one-to-many relationship with two tables.